# Upgrading to Yii2, ORM not functional

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, orm, yii2

I'm upgrading a big project form Yii1 to Yii2. I'm having some problems regarding to ORM.

I have several relation declared in the following fashion(basically a copy-paste from the [guidebook](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#hasOne()-detail)):

```
class Order extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {

/* other code */

public function getAffiliate()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Affiliate::className(), ['id_affiliate' => 'affiliate_id']);
}
```

Whenever I try to echo or w/e `$order->affiliate->name`; I get the following error:

```
yii\base\ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object
```

I've got no experience with Yii1 what so ever. Something weird about this project is the database. All tables start with `yii_tablename` and id's are: `id_tablename`. Was that normal for Yii1 and could this be causing the issue above?

*Edit*: When I execute the function like so: `$order->getAffilate()` it returns an ActiveQuery WITHOUT the data from the affiliate.

When I execute the following:

```
$order->getBillingAddress()->one();
```

I get a weird error:

```
Getting unknown property: app\models\Order::billing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. One which I don't really like though, but it does the job. Was reading this thread: [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/52360-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object/page__view__findpost__p__242276).

> Kartik V
>
> The problem is clearly in uniqueness in naming your relation and your model attribute. In your User model, you have an attribute named role and you also have a relation getter named getRole.

So I changed the name of the getter like so:

```
public function getOrderAffiliate()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Affiliate::className(), ['id_affiliate' => 'affiliate_id']);
}
```

And that fixed the issue. Never had this issue before and wonder why this happened though.

Answer (score 0):

```
return $this->hasOne(Affiliate::className(), ['id_affiliate' => 'affiliate_id']);
```

It's mean that when you call `$order->affiliate` yii2 will find in `Affiliate` table on `id_affiliate` field current `Order` `affiliate_id` value and selected `one` value.

Check that you have right field names and database have right data.

When you call `$order->affiliate` you will get `Affiliate` object. But if you call `$order->getAffiliate()` you will get `ActiveQuery` object.

Comment: Just added info that the activeQuery that returns displays the correct data, thanks anyway

Comment: Sorry I took another look at the data from the active Query and it returns data, but nothing from the affiliate. That was stupid of me..

Comment: Check that `id_affiliate` is exist in `Affiliate` table. and `affiliate_id` in `Order`. Next check that ids is correct. API your code is right.

Comment: The `Order` and `Affiliate` both exist in the database. All data directly from the `Order` gets displayed on the page without any issues.